# How can I add the functionality in Rails where a user can delete himself or herself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in my Users controller in Rails to let users delete themselves:

```
def delete_account
User.find(params[:id]).destroy
flash[:success] = "Your account has been deleted."
redirect_to root_path
end
```

Now, I'm unsure of how to add the proper route to my route.rb file and then add the button correctly into my user settings view.
For my route file I have the following code:

```
match '/delete_account' to: 'users#delete_account'
```

And in my settings view file I have the following code to add a button for the delete_account action in the view:

```
<%= link_to class: "btn btn-danger", delete_account_path %>\
```

Any help you can provide in implementing the correct route and embedded ruby in my view would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if this is an easy error to fix; I'm a beginner developer, and this has been giving me some trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better to use RESTful way.

Rename your method to `destroy` in controller.

In your routes.rb,

`resources :users` or `match '/delete_account', to: 'users#destroy'`

In the view, say in show.html.erb,

`<%= link_to 'Delete', @user, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>`

And obvious your `show` action should find the right user,

`@user = User.find(params[:id])`